# Ruby on Rails model field updates through console, not through browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I noticed that one of my model fields would not update through my app in the browser after it had been initially set. When I went to investigate this I discovered that the field was only declared through a custom validator:

```
validate :amount_validator

def amount_validator
    if self.amount == nil
        errors.add(:amount, "Please fill in the amount.")
    end
end
```

I thought the issue was that this was missing:

```
validates :amount, presence: true
```

I added this but I still couldn't update the field through the browser. When I saved the value and the page refreshed it had reverted to its original value. I read another SO question that indicated I should try updating this field through the console and see if there were any errors. I did this, it worked with no errors. Went back into the browser and the value had changed but I still could not update it through the browser. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just notice the console where you ran the server, what error message it prints.. or *.log file...

Comment: Can you check in logs or browser console on parameters getting passed? Is value for this field getting sent?

Comment: There is no error, it detects the change (and the new value), seems to commit it, but the value does not actually change.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? If Rails 4, did you add it to allowed attributes in your strong parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what rails version you're using, the error might be around [accessible attributes](http://jaked409.livejournal.com/93475.html) (Rails 3) or [strong paramenters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) (Rails 4).

On Rails 3, make sure that you have this in your **model**:

```
attr_accessible :amount
```

On Rails 4, make sure that you are allowing the attribute in the hash that you pass to `update_attributes` in your **controller**:

```
your_model.update_attributes(params.require(:your_model_name).permit([:amount]))
```